# Running perl function in background or separate process

Tags: perl, apache, process, background-process

I'm running in circles.  I have webpage that creates a huge file.  This file takes forever to be created and is in a subroutine.

What is the best way for my page to run this subroutine but not wait for it to be created/processed? Are there any issues with apache processes since I'm doing this from a webpage?

Comment: Can you fork off a child process in the subroutine to create the file?

Comment: I've tried this and it works 50% of the time.  Not sure why it fails and if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to perform this task is to simply use `fork()` and have the long-running subroutine run in the child process.  Meanwhile, have the parent return to Apache.  You indicate that you've tried this already, but absent more information on exactly what the code looks like and what is failing it's hard to help you move forward on this path.

Another option is to have run a separate process that is responsible for managing the long-running task.  Have the webpage send a unit of work to the long-running process using a local socket (or by creating a file with the necessary input data), and then your web script can return immediately while the separate process takes care of completing the long running task.

This method of decoupling the execution is fairly common and is often called a "task queue" (if there is some mechanism in place for queuing requests as they come in).  There are a number of tools out there that will help you design this sort of solution (but for simple cases with filesystem-based communication you may be fine without them).

Comment: When you fork, make sure the child process closes STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR. Otherwise, they'll still be connected to the webserver and it won't realize close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create a worker grandchild of Apache -- that is:

```
Apache -> child -> grandchild
```

where the child dies right after forking the grandchild, and the grandchild closes STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR. (The grandchild then creates the file.) These are the basic steps in creating a zombie daemon (a parent-less worker process unconnected with the webserver).